# Select an unpersisted entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using a twig for loop to display a list of elements. These elements come from a decoded json array, from an API.

I have a OneToMany relation between my user and these elements.

User needs to chose one of these elements, which will be added to the user with the addElement() function.

I tried to do so using a Symfony2 form in the loop, but it is only displayed on the first element. I also tried using a link to a controller function, but since none of these elements are persisted in my DB, I got this error:

```
"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information."
```

Here's how I display my elements:

```
{% block itinerary %}
    {% for element in elements %}

<aside class="flights-results__by-price col-md-3">
  <span class="flights-results__price">{{ element.price ? element.price : 'Unknown' }}</span>
  <a href="{{ path('selectLeg', {'element': element}) }}">Delete</a>
</aside>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock itinerary %}
```

Here is the function where I create and fill my elements :

```
  public function getAvailabilities($availabilities, $planes,     $airports)
{
    $reservations = array();
    foreach ($availabilities as $ar)
    {
        $leg = new Leg();
        $leg->getId();
        foreach($ar as $a)
        {
            $leg = $this->fillLeg($leg, $a);
            foreach($a->availabilities as $aleg)
            {
                $leg->setAirplaneType($this->findPlane($planes, $aleg->airplane_type_id));
                $leg->setAirportStart($this->findAirport($airports, $a->lfi_from));
                $leg->setAirportEnd($this->findAirport($airports, $a->lfi_to));
                $leg->setDurationLeg($aleg->duration);
                $leg->setEndHour($aleg->datetime_to);
            }
            $startdate = $a->datetime;
        }
        $reservations[] = $leg;
    }
    return $reservations;
}
```

and here is the result when I dump($elements) :

```
FlightController.php on line 55:
array:4 [▼
  0 => {#953 ▼
    +"3e1f975601f59090decc8f2d5ced72010162e48e": {#954 ▼
  +"lfi_from": "FR58957"
  +"lfi_to": "FR45300"
  +"datetime": "2015-09-10 20:00:00"
  +"nb_pax": "4"
  +"availabilities": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#955 ▶}
  ]
}
  }
  1 => {#956 ▼
+"3e1f975601f59090decc8f2d5ced72010162e48e": {#957 ▼
  +"lfi_from": "FR45300"
  +"lfi_to": "AG00060"
  +"datetime": "2015-09-10 23:00:00"
  +"nb_pax": "4"
  +"availabilities": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#958 ▶}
  ]
}
}
2 => {#959 ▼
+"3e1f975601f59090decc8f2d5ced72010162e48e": {#960 ▼
  +"lfi_from": "FR45300"
  +"lfi_to": "AG00060"
  +"datetime": "2015-11-30 23:00:00"
  +"nb_pax": "4"
  +"availabilities": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#961 ▶}
  ]
}
}
3 => {#962 ▼
+"3e1f975601f59090decc8f2d5ced72010162e48e": {#963 ▼
  +"lfi_from": "FR45300"
  +"lfi_to": "OLOLOL"
  +"datetime": "2015-09-18 23:00:00"
  +"nb_pax": "2"
  +"availabilities": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#964 ▶}
  ]
 }
}
]
```

The main problem is that the API returns several thousands results. For obvious reasons, I cannot persist them all.

I guess the easiest way to ask would be "What is the best way to send datas on an entity to another function in my controller, without persisting this entity?". So far, I've always worked with persisted elements, with an id as identifier, but I realize it gets trickier when we deal with non-persisted entities.

Comment: Can you share some code so we can see what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Done, I added the for loop, and the link I tried earlier.

Comment: ... but we still miss the useful code : where do you create your JSON ? What is the value of `elements` ? What's your entities ? Besides, `l` in your Twig template doesn't refer to anything; the loop variable seems to be `element`...

Comment: Yes, my bad, "l" refers to element. I added the structure of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *OneToMany* relation between your `User` and these `Elements`, it means the Elements are persisted somehow. So why can't you use the `id` of the element ?

In case you persist it, you may need to add a *ParamConverter* in your controller code somewhere along those lines:

```
/**
  * @Route("/selectLeg/{element}")
  * @ParamConverter("element", class="YourBundle:Element", options={"mapping": {"name": "element.whatever_param"}})
  * @Template()
  */
public function selectLegAction(Element $element)
```

The fact is, if Symfony2 doesn't know about your `Element` entity, you won't be able to do `addElement()` to your `User`.

What I guess is that you get the elements' list in the frontend and then try to update your `User` object. In this case I would json_encode your element in Twig (it's a simple array after all if I understand) :

```
<a href="{{ path('selectLeg', {'legAsJSONString': element|json_encode}) }}">Select this leg</a>
```

and create a new `Element` in your controller :

```
/**
  * @Route("/selectLeg/{legAsJSONString}")
  */
public function selectLegAction($legAsJSONString) {

  $e = json_decode($legAsJSONString);

  $leg = new Leg();
  $leg->setWhateverParameter($e->parameter_in_the_array);
  // more parameters here
  $em->persist($leg)->flush();

  /// Now here you have $leg->getId(); if  ever you need it

}
```

**EDIT** : Adapted to your comment. If you don't need to persist the element (leg) before the user has chosen a particular one, then send the element in string form in a **GET** parameter, in the route parameters, or in the data of a **POST** request (cleaner solution). You don't need the id since you can pass the full object in the request, as a JSON string.

Remove your useless `$leg->getId();` from `getAvailabilities()` as well, it doesn't actually do anything, and the id doesn't exist anyway.

If I miss the point and that the `$leg` object is too complicated and therefore not serializable in JSON, then you **will** need to persist it since two consequent requests will need to have access to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, still facing the same problem: without persisting my entity, I cannot get an identifier to generate the route. I added the rest of my code, and changed the question to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: See my updated answer. To me, sending the full object via POST or GET is  your best solution since the object looks serializable. You don't need an identifier, then. If you can't do this, you **will need** to persist your Leg somewhere between two requests ...

Comment: I tried with your updated answer, I can send the element, but for some reason, the json is empty. However, I  tried to dump the element before the twig encoding, it was full. Although I don't know why it got cleared, I think I'm on the right direction for my problem.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `json_encode` options : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php. If you make it work consider accepting my answer as well ;)